# TTFB and gzip compression for HTTP response

Tags: apache, http, gzip

What is the impact of enabling gzip compression on Time-to-first-byte (TTFB)?

My assumption is that apache server cannot start streaming the response in parts while the request is being processed because gzip requires full response to be ready for the compression. Does this mean enabling gzip compression will increase TTFB?

Thanks.

Comment: gzip is capable of streaming.

Comment: Can gzip start streaming when it has received just few chunks/parts of the response from application? Any reference will be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: LionHeart: yes, it can. How about trying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with comment by [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) that gzip supports streaming. This means full response is not required before compression begins. In presence of gzip compression, the first byte will get delayed by time required to compress first sliding-window bytes of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php flush(); function to send the page header first (the browser will start the page render faster).

Gzip compression does take it's time, but usually it's about 10-40 milliseconds.